# MySQL - Where occurs at least 3 times

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have got this query, which works fine:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.ip as ip 
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON ( t2.id = t1.t2id )
ORDER BY t1.timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1000
```

What I would like to do is to:

1) get only those entries where the same `ip` occurs at least 3 times

2) group the entries by `ip`

So the result would look like this example:

```
IP                  TIMESTAMP
111.111.111.111     1500000000
111.111.111.111     1300000000
111.111.111.111     1100000000
222.222.222.222     1400000000
222.222.222.222     1300000000
222.222.222.222     1200000000
```

I have tried many approaches and I believe that this one is the closest,
but the result is 0 rows.

```
SELECT *, COUNT(DISTINCT ip) FROM ( 
    SELECT t1.*, t2.ip as ip 
    FROM table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON ( t2.id = t1.t2id )
    ORDER BY t1.timestamp DESC
    LIMIT 1000
) AS tmp_table 
GROUP BY ip
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ip) > 2
```

Please can someone shine some light on this?

Comment: If you group by only IP, you wouldn't have repeats of IP.  Could you clarify?

Comment: I don't understand the logic of using `distinct` either, since you want the *same* IP.

Comment: @rlanvin I thought COUNT(DISTINCT ip) would only get the count of the same ips. Is that not how it works?

Comment: @san.chez "but it doesn't return a single row." do you meant "but it does only return a single row per IP."?

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT ip)` means exactly that: "count the distinct IP". So N occurrences of the *same* ip will only be counted once.

Comment: COUNT(DISTINCT ip) will always return 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *, COUNT(ip) FROM ( 
    SELECT t1.*, t2.ip as ip 
    FROM table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON ( t2.id = t1.t2id )
    ORDER BY t1.timestamp DESC
    LIMIT 1000
) AS tmp_table 
GROUP BY ip
HAVING COUNT(ip) > 2
```

just remove distinct

Comment: It works and it is pretty quick for LIMIT 1000 :) 38 total, Query took 0.1083 seconds. However it returns only one row for each IP, but I need all of them.

Comment: Then select ip from this result for left join table1, ``` select * from table1 left join on (select ip from ( the resutls)) table4 on table1.ip = table4.ip```

Comment: The `on` in ` left join on` part is highliting as an error, I tried to remove it but got `Syntax error or access violation: 1248 Every derived table must have its own alias`

Comment: I have fixed the error but now the query exhausts the allowed memory size of 268M, I am going to do a second query on click I think.

Comment: How about add limit 1000 at the end, maybe the table is too big.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.*, (SELECT DISTINCT t2.ip FROM t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.t2id)
FROM t1
WHERE
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM t2
    WHERE t2.id = t1.t2id) >= 3
```

Bacause in the comments has resulted table t2 with more rows for the same IP I change my query as follow:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.ip
FROM t1
JOIN t2
    ON t2.id = t1.t2id
WHERE
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM t2 tt2
    WHERE t2.ip = tt2.ip) >= 3
```

You can see [**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4e90/1/0)

Comment: I am getting 0 rows result. Even with >=2. But there are duplicates in the database so should return something.

Comment: Dear, t2id for the same IP is the same or different? Please post in your question data set of t1 and data set of t2

Comment: t2 table: id, ip, ....  t1 table:  id, t2id, ..... Where t2id is a foreign key joining the two tables.

Comment: @san.chez: So, in t2 there's one row for one IP?

Comment: No, there could be more then one rows with the same ip.

Comment: So your table isn't normalized, I suppose

Comment: Why do you think it isn't?

Comment: Because if you create a link between t1 and t2, where t2 has as important info the IP you have more rows with the same IP each of them with the other different infos. If you add in your question the data sets of two tables

Comment: The purpose of t2 table is not what you think it is. Thank you for your effort anyway, much appreciated.

Comment: @san.chez: Dear, I've updated my answer, I suppose now it's OK

Answer (score 1):

You have to have the `HAVING` in the subquery

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.ip as ip 
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON ( t2.id = t1.t2id ) 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT t2.ip
    FROM table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table1 t2 ON ( t2.id = t2.t2id )
    GROUP BY t2.ip
    HAVING count(ip) > 2
) t ON t2.ip = t.ip
```

Comment: it is an alias for the subquery. do get any syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this;

```
SELECT t2.ip as ip 
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON ( t2.id = t1.t2id )
where t2.ip IN (SELECT ip FROM ( 
    SELECT t2.ip as ip 
    FROM table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON ( t2.id = t1.t2id )
    ) AS tmp_table 
    GROUP BY ip
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 2)
ORDER BY t1.timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: This query takes forever even if do LIMIT 10

Comment: What time would inner select takes ? Actually, It is a hard operation which you try to apply for database. Determine the recurring ip addresses and apply perform on it.

Comment: If by 'inner select' you mean `SELECT ip ...` this is the result: (11177 total, Query took 1.5466 seconds.)

Comment: There are a lot of texts to be applied in where clause. Would you remove the "t1.timestamp DESC" ?